# How to prove that $Z_m \times Z_n $ is isomorphic to $Z_{mn}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have come across proof which is given below.
[image]

I could not understand the step which is highlighted by an arrow on the right panel.
Namely How do we get f(u(1-ms)+v(1-nt))=(u+mZ,v+nZ)

Please help with the explanation.

Comment: Note that $1-nt=ms$, so $v(1-ms)$ is a multiple of $m$; so the image of $u(1-ms)+v(1-ut)$ modulo $m$ is $u(1-ms)+m\mathbb{Z}=u+m\mathbb{Z}$ (since $u(1-ms)=u-ums$, and $ums$ is *also* a multiple of $m$). So the image in the first component is just $u$. A symmetric argument shows the image on the second component is just $v+n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin . I could not understand your argument. Here f(u(1-ms)+v(1-nt))=((u(1-ms)+v(1-nt))+mZ , (u(1-ms)+v(1-nt))+nZ). But how is that (u(1-ms)+v(1-nt))+mZ=u+mZ and (u(1-ms)+v(1-nt))+nZ=v+nZ. Am i missing some properties of a coset

Comment: How? For **exactly** the reason I said. Also, please use MathJax; it is very difficult to read your ASCII. You’ve been in this site for 10 months. There is no excuse for you to not format your posts or comments correctly.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sure will do. And sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks for your help.